# Crystal Reports Sequence for Fields

Tags: crystal-reports, sum, sequence, sum-of-digits

I'm pretty new on using Crystal Reports.
So, in the picture below:

[image: Records]

I need the first value in the table (1,041,410.00, 1,300,084.00) to add themselves up for every new date in the table.

For example: In the third row of 12/30/2011, the values are 1,041,410.00, the next is 0.00 then -21,950 and so on.

Instead of displaying the records as it is, i need it to display its previous value PLUS its new value. So instead of the above, i need it to display this instead:

1,041,410.00 then 1,041,410.00 (Because 1,041,410.00 + 0.00 is the same) then 1,019,460 (1,041,410.00 - 21,950) then 1,007,160.00 (1,019,460 - 12,300) and so on. I need a formula as i'm not very good at programming.

Comment: use running total.. condition would be evalaute on change of every record and reset as never

Comment: Could you please post images of your CR report ? Only the details section

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want a [Running Total](https://kb.blackbaud.com/articles/Article/37860) for this. There's a very handy Wizard for creating one of these. To start, right click *Running Total Fields* in your Field Explorer and select *New*.

[image]

Select the field you want to summarize, and you're probably good to go. (In your case the default settings should suffice.)

If for some reason you're not able to get the Running Total to work, you can otherwise use a Shared Variable. There's a few more steps involved, so I'd recommend sticking with the RT if possible.